# Show Related Items

Tags: usability, gui-design, interface, flow

What is a good user experience for a single web page that allows the user to add and manage 3 related things?

In my case I want the user to see this in the UI:

```
Property 1
   Building 1
      Apartment 1
      Apartment 2
Property 2
   Building 1
   Building 2
      Apartment 1
```

I tried showing it like that with expandable widgets, but it quickly becomes a mess. Not to mention it is a headache to add new buildings or apartments in this mess I created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it becoming "a mess"? How exactly does it harm the user experience?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned wanting the user to "add and manage" 3 related things. And then your diagram shows a nested list, like in a shopping site.

"Add and manage" sounds like it's probably a different design pattern than a standard navigation for a website. So we'll probably need more details.

What is the total number of items the user can choose from? A few dozen, or hundreds? How does the person select an item to put into this state? Can you explain more about the use case you are attempting to enable?

Comment: Great questions!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is considered expandable widget.

But using multiple level navigation menu should meet your needs.

[image]

If you feel that this is still messy, you could also consider using slightly different shades of colour for the nested menus.

[image]

For your reference:

https://codyhouse.co/demo/multi-level-accordion-menu/index.html